# How can I create a liferay 6.0.6 project with maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, liferay

I want to create a liferay 6.0.6 portlet with maven.
Is maven supported in liferay 6.0.6?
If yes, How can I create a project with maven for liferay 6.0.6 in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

Liferay supports maven. For creating portlet using maven, you can refer this.

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-plugins-with-maven